# Вернуть Настройки по умолчанию IntelljIdea

Tags: intellij-idea

Как в IntelljIdea сбросить настройки по умолчанию?
Мне нужно вернуть стандартное расположение всех окон. У меня стали очень неудобно распологаться.

Answer (score 4):

1 В главном меню выберите:
если интерфейс на русском
**Файл | Управление настройками IDE | Восстановить настройки по умолчанию**.
если интерфейс на английском
**File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings**.

---

2 или просто в главном окне 2 раза нажмите `Shift` и напишите `Restore default settings`

---

3 Щелкните Восстановить и перезапустить. Среда IDE будет перезапущена с конфигурацией по умолчанию.
[image: 2 вариант]